# How much processing power would a real time Edited Reality headset need to render video in real time

Tags: science-based, technology

Imagine a VR headset with built in camera & AI with object recognition & photo editing software.

The camera records the image.

The AI is trained to pick out 'undesirable' images, objects, shapes & faces.

Which it edits out & replaces with the correct / extrapolated background from earlier footage.

> The same is of course done for any undesirable sounds (or voices) with [active noise control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control) headphones built into the headset.

Rendering these doctored images in real time so the wearer doesn't experience any noticeable or significant (or dangerous) delay between events & seeing them may take a lot of processing power.

So the question, how much processing power is needed (for [hi definition video quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-definition_video) in real time)?

Oh! & (assuming current technology) how heavy will the chips be that we need?

Comment: Can you define "undesirable"?

Comment: @Ryan_L : Nope, the user defines 'undesirable', it might be a specific person, all people, cats, dogs, billboards advertising tampons, what's 'undesirable' is entirely within the gift of the owner of this device.

Comment: And I assume the user also defines what to replace the undesirable images with?

Comment: Are you looking for an actual number, or just a generalized answer of the kind of necessary processing capabilities?

Comment: @overlord : Generalised, if I wanted an exact figure I'd have tagged it hard-science rather than science :)

Comment: @Pelinore Not all people know which tags are appropriate, I was just double-checking.

Comment: @Ryan_L : That option is available as an upgrade (it's where we make a lot of our profit. by the time they've had a couple of accidents walking into things they can't see most people are willing to pay our exorbitant fee for it), the standard model makes the undesired object 'invisible' by rendering in whatever is behind it.

Comment: That seems impossible.  How can your system possibly know what's behind something?  I mean it's possible in some cases; the sky behind a billboard shouldn't be hard to fake, but what about things it can't guess?  Like perhaps people in a crowd.  If it's supposed to filter out the front people, how does it know what the people in back look like?

Comment: @Ryan : "how does it know what the people in back look like?" from the small print at the bottom of our rental contract > 'the system isn't perfect & you should expect the odd void or blurred image on occasion'

Comment: @Pelinore so the big question here is "How perfect this system needs to be?" Is it Ok to just blur undesired images or replace them with regular texture, or it needs to produce an accurate representation of the world behind those images?

Comment: @Alexander : An accurate image, blurs & voids are still expected once in a while, particularly with something that can't be extrapolated (ie you've decided you don't want to see wooden planks for some peculiar reason & a stranger who's face you've not seen turns around just as someone carries a plank of wood between you & him) but otherwise it should be as good as a person can achieve going through the footage frame by frame

Comment: @Alexander : ^ With all frames from a minute or two b4 to use for images to fill in the blanks in each frame.

Comment: “Real time” is not possible with any amount of computer power, the information will always travel no faster than the speed of light. So you really need to define what “real time” means in this question - how much delay is acceptable?

Comment: @VogonPoet : Consider 'real time' to mean the same as it does for a phone conversation or live TV, we want rendering fast enough to allow someone wearing one to catch a gently tossed ball at least, the micro-delay of speed of light seriously isn't what I meant :)

Comment: I don't get it. Augmented reality / mixed reality headsets are a real thing, for example Microsoft's [HoloLens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_HoloLens). What is this question asking which cannot be found in the specs of those headsets.

Comment: @AlexP : I don't get it / you're saying there are ***any*** '_mixed reality_' headsets out there that provide any apps or functionality to do this to any extent at all, because I've not seen them, would love a link if there are? bear in mind I'm not in any way talking about simply overlaying images on a HUD, I'm talking about providing full photoshopping frame by frame in real time as it happens to remove selected objects & individuals & replace them with seamlessly photoshopped images as if they were never there in the first place.

Comment: A side Q: where is the power coming from? A battery will be heavy, beamed energy will cook the brain of the wearer.

Answer (score 5):

**If we take as baseline current PC reqs, we have CPU I5 + 500/600 USD video card.**

So let's forget about the CPU focus on the GPU for a while.
Let's take as reference Nvidia Gforce RTX 2080.
They got a different architecture than a CPU because it is specialized hardware. 13.6 **b**illion transistiors, 2944 processing cores. **The boosted clock gives 1.700 MHz with a bandwith of 448 GB per second.**

Without going into the CPU you already got an issue of power supply (215 watts) and proper cooling.

Card alone stands around 700 grams, no packaging.

Now the I5 CPU weights about 200 grams. Let's say it got **4 cores, 8 threads and about 4.20 GHz**. maybe more, maybe less.

So summing up, bare minimum a kilogram of hardware with current tech.
The specs can be looked up on gaming websites but the previous info gives you a solid baseline.

Comment: We want rendering fast enough for someone wearing one to catch a gently tossed ball & we're using 1,, (um, actually 2 if we want depth perception) high definition video cameras, can this handle that without substantial lag?

Comment: Indeed. The main issue with current hardware is size. For a PC with access to 220v that is a non issue. For a wereable device, it will run hot and be uncomfortable. Unless you carry a backpack with all the doodas and stream the images to the headset.

Comment: WiFi with the bulk of the processing done elsewhere then perhaps?

Comment: That sounds like a plan. If you wish to make it look more futuristic while using current existing tech, use Li-Fi. That is wifi by light. got a bruuuutal speed.

Comment: Hmm.. that's a new one on me, but I'd have thought LiFi would pose problems for wearable devices (I'm assuming the 'Li is for 'light'), needs a line of sight surely? going to be a beam right? .. can be blocked by walking into (or behind) a building? turning around would lose the connection no? .. goes away to Google it.

Comment: You can also probably wear the components somehow attached to your clothes. Chainmail is *heavy* when in a bundle but apparently not THAT noticeable when you wear it and the weight is distributed on your body. So if you apply the same, you could have a "vest" of processing units to wear. It would probably keep you quite warm, though, so make sure you only put it on in the winter.

Comment: @VLAZ agree. A modern soldier carries 30 kilograms of gear and they run with that.

Comment: @Gustavo They also hate it and it ruins their knees and backs.  Not the kind of thing you'll convince many consumers to use.

Comment: So essentially get a decent gaming laptop in your backpack plus a helmet the size and weight of a motor cycle helmet.

Comment: @quarague the helmet is your run of the mill Oculus or similar gadget. The analogy of gaming laptop is quite accurate. Main issue is the AI the original post asked. That may need more powerfull hardware for the AI to live. OR, use your CAR, since Tesla has its own computer. And stream the data to your comfy headset. Tha way it can be a heavy suitcase and eat ton of power, yet the user can walk around unhindered.

Answer (score 2):

In my eye, the limiting factor might be RAM.  The human eye has a resolution of about 120 megapixels.  Given 32bit color, meaning each pixel takes 32bits to store, we're looking at needing ~56 gigabytes of RAM just to store one second worth of video.  You can't compress it, because you need the raw video to do your filtering.  This isn't counting whatever else you have to store to do the calculations, like your archive of undesirable images.  It's also not counting anything to do with audio.  I don't think it's far-fetched to say we're looking at a terabyte of RAM.  The first RAM chip I could find on Amazon is 16gb, costs $77, and weighs 3.2 ounces.  So using those, you're looking at almost \$5000 and *13 pounds* just in RAM.

Comment: The human eye does not have a resolution of about 120 megapixels, not even close. You are wrong by an order of magnitude. Simple experiment: go to a shop selling fancy TV sets. Find a large 4K TV showing an image; that's 8 megapixels. Approach the the TV set until it covers a field of view of about 90° (outside this field of view the discriminating power of human eyes is very low and can be safely disregarded). Can you see individual pixels?

Comment: @AlexP I just googled "resolution of human eye" and used this article from Forbes:
https://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2016/10/06/what-is-the-resolution-of-the-human-eye-in-megapixels/#2a4292965912

Comment: *Forbes*, the well-known source for anatomical and physiological information. In brief, the acuity of the human eye is not constant over the entire field of view. There is a central area of maximum acuity, where the eye can distinguish points at about 0.5 minute of arc separation; say that this covers 10°, and let's bump the acuity to 0.25 minutes of arc. This gives about 12 megapixels equivalent resolution for the central area. The rest, up to 90° is much coarser, but let's be generous and add 12 megapixels more. Total is about 24 megapixels and that's with *very* favourable approximations.

Comment: If you prefer hard anatomical data, a foveal cone, that is a cone in the region of maximum acuity, subtends about 15 arc seconds...

Comment: Your estimate of 3.2 ounces or roughly 80 grams for 16gb is nowhere close to optimal either. You can get ram chips of 64 gb which immediately cuts your estimate by a factor of 4. 80 grams also seems high and might include some packaging.